# WebApi Restricting Access via config file

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

With WebAPI, you can restrict access by user-name with the overload Authorize attribute

```
// Restrict by user:
[Authorize(Users="Alice,Bob")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
}
```

Is there a way to set these in the web.config file?

(Matching to Controller(class) or individual Methods on a Controller)

I've looked and looked...and the searches are too ambiguous. (too many results or not many).